# Inserting non-ASCII characters into a Unicode defined column in Teradata using pyodbc

Tags: python, utf-8, odbc, teradata, pyodbc

I am attempting to use pyodbc to insert a list of lists into a Teradata table with the target column defined as varchar Unicode.

Any letter beyond the standard ascii 127 code point appears to come in as two characters. For example ü comes over as Ã¼ into the table.

UTF-8 characters also come across incorrectly.

’ comes over as â and two unprintable characters after it (PAD,and SGCI according to notepad++)

If I change the setencoding in the python script to latin1 it inserts the latin characters correctly,  but of course when it gets to a non-Latin, character (in my case \u2019) it exits with an ordinal not in range error.

Characters below code point 127 come across fine.  When I print the string to the console after setting PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8  and right before insertion, the string looks as it should, I see the ü. And ’

**EDIT 2:**

As it turns out, this may not have anything to do with pyodbc at all

```
           print(item)
           print(item.encode('utf-8'))
```

Yields:

Classificação

b'Classifica\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'

And those code points correspond to what I am seeing in the database:

Ã§Ã£

The item variable is type str.

Shouldn't the byte string be e7 and e3? in other words:

b'Classifica\xe7\xe3o'

**EDIT:**

An example, the incorrect text and corresponding hex (according to Teradata's char2hexint function)

aÃ§Ã£o,006100C300A700C300A3006F

I am expecting:
ação,006100E700E3006F

Per the pyodbc documentation: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode I have setup my connection as follows:

```
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8') 

cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8') 

cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-8') 

cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
```

Software

```
    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo) 
    Teradata Drivers 15.10.01.14 
    Teradata Database version 15.10.X 
    Python version: Anaconda - Python 3.6.3  
    Pyodbc version: pyodbc-4.0.17
```

This is the DSN Entry:

```
   [server] 
    Driver=<validpath>/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so 
    Description=Teradata ODBC 
    CharacterSet=UTF8 
    DBCName=server 
    EnableDataEncryption=Yes 
    EnableLOBs=Yes 
    EnableReconnect=No 
    IntegratedSecurity=No 
    LoginTimeout=20 
    MapCallEscapeToExec=No 
    MaxRespSize=1048576 
    PortNumber=1025 
    PrintOption=N 
    ProcedureWithSplSource=Y 
    ReportCodePageConversionErrors=0 
    ShowSelectableTables=Yes 
    Trace=Yes 
    TraceFile=/tmp/trace.log
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a problem of inspecting the data in the DB? Because it could be that the data get properly saved (`ü` as its UTF-8 representation `C3 BC`), but when you look at what was saved, these two bytes are erroneously interpreted with Latin-1, which gives `Ã¼`.

Comment: @lenz   See my update. In addition I've verified I am connecting with the charset property set to utf8 in my query tool.

Comment: Ok, I might actually be of little help here because I don't know how to configure this DB correctly. But I can tell you that the hex representations of "ação" is `61 C3 A7 C3 A3 6F`, there are no `00` bytes for this string. What you have there looks like UTF-16. But that's probably alright if the DB is using UTF-16 internally and you only tell it how the strings are encoded for transmission.

Comment: Are you using Python 2, by any chance? In that case you definitely need to show how you get the string values and how you send them to the DB. It's possible that you have an implicit unicode/str coercion.

Comment: @lenz No I am using python 3

Comment: I am going to re-ask this in a new question

Comment: @ your edit 2: no, the byte string `b'Classifica\xe7\xe3o'` would be the Latin-1 encoding of "Classificação". The UTF-8 encoding is `b'Classifica\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'`. Do not confuse Unicode code points (`U+E7` for "ç") with the byte values of their physical encoding (`C3 A7` for UTF-8).